# Sustituir valor dentro de una consulta en postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Buen dia. Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
COPY (SELECT 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."ID_UR", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."IDEDOMUN15", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX1", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX2", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX3", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX4", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX5", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX6", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX7", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX8", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX9", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX10", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX11", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX12", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX13", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX14", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX15", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX16" 
 FROM 
 public."UR_16PIX_Chih"
 WHERE 
 "UR_16PIX_Chih"."IDEDOMUN15" = '08061') TO 
 '/home/manager/data/miconsulta/08061.csv' WITH CSV HEADER;
```

Lo que quiero saber es como puedo sustituir automaticamente el valor '08061' por el valor 08062, luego por el valor 08063, después por el valor 08062 y así sucesivamente. Solo en la consulta no en la tabla. Hasta ahora lo que hago es editar la consulta e ir cambiando el valor manualmente pero necesito hacerlo de una forma automática. Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: Como te indican en la respuesta, el camino a ese tipo de problemas siempre será plsql (o plpgsql en este caso)

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacer algo como:

```
DO 
$_$
DECLARE 
    r record;
BEGIN 
FOR r IN SELECT "IDEDOMUN15"  as i FROM "UR_16PIX_Chih" GROUP BY "IDEDOMUN15" LOOP
    COPY (
        SELECT 
            "ID_UR", 
            ... -- acá todos tus campos
            "PIX16" 
         FROM 
            public."UR_16PIX_Chih"
         WHERE 
            "IDEDOMUN15" = r.i) TO '/home/manager/data/miconsulta/'||r.i||'.csv' WITH CSV HEADER;
END LOOP;
END;
$_$
language plpgsql;
```

Básicamente tienes un bloque DO que itera sobre todos los distintos valores de un campo de tu tabla y crea un archivo csv para cada uno.

Comment: Gracias, Bernardo!. La probaré y ya te cuento. Saludos